# What does choice mean in "for choice in question.choice_set.all" from the Django poll tutorial?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and am working through the first poll tutorial. I'm having trouble understanding the use of the word "choice" in a for loop within the tutorial.

I've read other questions related to this part of the tutorial, but most dealt with choice_set.all

```
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

My question is related to the initial use of the word choice in the for statement... for "choice" in.

It appears to be referencing the whole Choice model which I don't quite understand. It seems like it would make more sense to say "for choice.choice_text in" while looping through checking for choice_text matches against values in question.choice_set.all.

The Choice model contains choice_text, question, and votes at this point of the tutorial.

Can someone help me understand what the first mention of choice refers to in the for loop?

Comment: Don't start with Django without learning the basics of Python first. This is a standard Python `for` loop.

Comment: choice is just a variable and you can name is anything, but you can do `for choice.choice_text in ...`, because that will be incorrect. As @Selcuk said it's basic python, you need to learn that first

Comment: Thanks. I understand the basics of a Python for loop, but am still having trouble with this syntax. I would have thought any word could have been used in place of choice there, but it doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: @user11048935 Did you change `choice` in both places?

Comment: To clarify... if I change that word choice to something else like baseball, the html renders as a blank list... just vertical list dots. If I change it back to the word choice, it correctly displays a list of choice_text variables from the Choice model. I'm not sure why that's the case. Note, this code is within an html template.

Comment: Yes, but did you also change the second instance to `{{ baseball.choice_text }}`?

Comment: @user11048935 `choice` is a random variable, it can be anything. You must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @malberts ha, no I did not. That worked. Ok I realize I have A LOT to learn. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`question.choice_set.all` is an iterable, such as a list or set and `choice` is the current items from within that iterable that you are operating upon, it could have been given any name other than a reserved word but since it is an item where the user is making a choice the authors decided it would be clearer to call it choice rather than `i` or `fred` but just about anything would have worked.

Once you have your item you can then get into the structure of it.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. When I change the word choice to any random word, the html is rendered as a blank list... with just vertical dots displayed. However when the actual word choice is used there it displays the proper character variables along side each list point that are stored in the Choice model's choice_text field. It doesn't look like any random word works there, but instead seems like it actually requires the word choice.

Comment: thank you. I realize what I was doing wrong now. I was confused by the fact that they used the name of our database model there instead of a random word. Reading up more on Python now. I appreciate you helping.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Steve Barnes' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54643844/4082726): you can indeed use any word instead of `choice`, but you have to make sure you use that same word in other places. For example:

```
{% for baseball in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ baseball.choice_text }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks again. I really appreciate it.